# send/receive mail from OWIN self-host webapp with custom domain

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, owin, self-hosting, amazon-ses

I have a domain, a Console Application with OWIN self-host.

The Console app host on AWS EC2 server windows server 2012.

My mail feature of server is sending Verification Mail

I've google many owin mail send or receive infomation,
but all of them are smtp/pop3 on google or some other smtp/pop3 server.

Is it possible to do send / receive mail in a console with current ip or custom domain?

---

I've try method.

1. Use hMailServer:

No luck in this. can't send/receive any mail, and set gmail for add smtp and pop3,
but fail.
the error msg: "We were unable to locate the other domain. Please contact your other provider."

2. Use AWS SES:

Still fail on this.
AWS SES need vail domain with anyaccount@domain, but i have no mail feature on my server.

3. Use my gmail:

Connect gmail need SSL. I have no SSL.
And research hours for host ssl on OWIN self-host,

Is there other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I set a **DNS MX Record** from my DNS provider.
Now,I can send/receive mail with hamilserver and gmail smtp/pop3.

not best solution, but my problem solved.